# Should we consolidate National ID Number tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just added a tag for [`national-id-number`](//expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-id-number) to [this question](//expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/32/51) for the purpose of easily finding questions related to the various National Identification Numbers used around the world.

Should we still have separate tags for specific national versions of these like `SSN` for the USA or `BSN` for the Netherlands or `NI-Num` for the UK?

Answer (score 6):

Such consilidation is dangerous if based on false premises. There are many different IDs, that have many different purposes: passports, personal IDs, national IDs (something like SSN in USA), tax ids etc.

If the question is about the documents allowing to identify a person, maybe [identification](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) would be the best. However, please allow specific tags, if used for specific purposes. For example, [ssn](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssn) for questions about getting SSN in USA.

Answer (score 5):

I propose that we consolidate all national identification numbers into one tag.  Questions should anyway be tagged with the country, and [national-id-number](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-id-number) along with a country-specific tag should be enough to find country-specific questions.

The only exception I can think of is if a country has *multiple* systems for national id numbers.  But that should apply only to a small minority of questions, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is no National Identity number in the UK.

There is a National Insurance Number, but on the National Insurance Number card it specifically says "This is not proof of identity". I think it's worth respecting that, and not merging it with the "national-id-number" tag. They are definitely not the same thing. The NI Number is closer to a personal tax number than an ID number.

As per Łukasz 웃 L ツ, there will be different purposes and different numbers. If we merge things, we should do so with a clear understanding of what the numbers mean, rather than merging and regretting it later.